# How to Set Readline key bindings in both vi-command and vi-insert modes

Tags: readline

To use the Emacs transpose-words function in vi mode I have the following .inputrc:

```
$if mode=vi
  bind Control-b: transpose-words
$endif
```

Unfortunately it only works in "insert" mode. What is the trick to make it work in both "insert" and "command" modes?

I tried to use **set keymap vi-command** in the file, but it has no effect.

```
$if mode=vi
  set keymap vi-command
  bind Control-b: transpose-words
$endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The "bind" keyword should not be in inputrc. The following inputrc works as intended. Ctrl-B transpose words in both insert and command mode:

```
set editing-mode vi
$if mode=vi
  set keymap vi-command
  Control-b: transpose-words
  set keymap vi-insert
  Control-b: transpose-words
$endif
```